# Is $\{0\}$ a *prime* ideal in $(\mathbb{Z}_2,\oplus,\odot)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

In my textbook (Abstract Algebra by Saracino), it gives $(\mathbb{Z}_2,\oplus,\odot)$ as an example of a commutative ring that has a maximal ideal that is not prime. It claims that the trivial ideal $\{0\}$ (which is maximal because it's the only ideal) is not prime. But the only way to express $0$ as the product of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is $1 \cdot 0 = 0 \cdot 1 = 0 \cdot 0$. In each case, $0$ appears as a factor, and $0 \in \{0\}$. So wouldn't this imply that $\{0\}$ *is* a prime ideal of $(\mathbb{Z}_2,\oplus,\odot)$?  I just want to make sure I'm not crazy here...

This is the textbook's definition of prime:

Let $R$ be a ring, $I$ an ideal in $R$. Then $I$ is **prime** if whenever $a,b \in R$ and $ab \in I$, then at least one of $a$ or $b$ is in $I$.

Comment: Usually we require $I\neq R$ in the definition of prime ideal. This corresponds to how $1$ isn't considered a prime number. Not that it changes your situation.

Comment: Erm, I don't get what you mean. $\{0\} \neq \mathbb{Z}_2$. Based on my book's definition of prime ideal, would $\{0\}$ be considered a prime ideal? (I just want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding it.)

Answer (score 4):

Usually, we consider $\{0\}$ to be a prime ideal in any (commutative, unital) ring without zero divisors. The alternative is just cumbersome.

A ring is an integral domain iff $\{0\}$ is prime. $I\subseteq R$ is prime iff $R/I$ is an integral domain. Formulating these and similar statements while trying to take into account that $\{0\}$ can't be prime just isn't worth the hassle.

This also makes every maximal ideal into a prime ideal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though $(\mathbb{Z}_2,\oplus,\odot)$ doesn't have a unity...

Comment: @Leonidas it does. $1$ is the multiplicative identity ("unity") in $\mathbb Z/2$.

Comment: @paul blart math cop: Hmm, this is weird. My book says "$R$ is a commutative ring *without* unity...". But now that you mention it, I agree that 1 must be the unity of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ because $0 \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot 0 = 0$ and $1 \cdot 1 = 1$.

Comment: @Leonidas your definition of multiplication in $\mathbb Z/2$ is wrong. The correct answer in $1*1=1$, unlesd your book is utterly nonstandard (which it might be, seeing as how it doesn't think all maximal ideals are prime...)

Comment: @paulblartmathcop: Not sure why you're writing $\mathbb{Z}/2$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. I agree that $1 \cdot 1 = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. (I'm just using $\cdot$ to denote multiplication mod 2.)

Comment: @Leonidas I disagree with calling this ring $\mathbb Z_2$. To me, that is the ring of $2$-adic integers and it is much more clear to me to write $\mathbb Z/2$ as the ring with two elements here. Regardless, I see the issue. The standard multiplication of $\mathbb Z/2$ makes it into a unital ring with $1*1=1$, but the counterexample of your book is taking $1*1=0$ as its definition. In this definition $\mathbb Z/2$ is nonunital and $\{0\}$ is not prime as $1 \notin \{0\}$ but $1*1=0 \in \{0\}$.

Comment: @Leonidas I'd like to mention that this is just a guess - I don't have the text in front of me - but I think this interpretation makes the most sense.